# How can I annotate a django queryset with more than one values

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I have an application that scrapes some eshops every day, and I record the `Price` of every `Item`.

A simplified version of my models looks like this:

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True)


class Price(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey("Item", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    per_item = models.FloatField(blank=True)
```

And my tables can look like this:

```
# Item

id  | name
-----------
1i  | item-1
2i  | item-2
3i  | item-3

# Price

id  | item   | timestamp   | per_item
--------------------------------------
1p  | i1     | 2023-04-10  | 10.0
2p  | i2     | 2023-04-10  | 2.0
3p  | i3     | 2023-04-10  | 14.5

4p  | i1     | 2023-04-11  | 11.0
5p  | i3     | 2023-04-11  | 12.5

6p  | i2     | 2023-04-12  | 2.0
7p  | i3     | 2023-04-12  | 14.5

8p  | i1     | 2023-04-13  | 12.0
9p  | i2     | 2023-04-13  | 3.5
10p | i3     | 2023-04-13  | 15.0
```

Note that not all Items exist every day, some of them may be present today, missing tomorrow and back again on the day after, and so on.

#### What I want to do

I'm trying to write a query that for a given day it will give me the **last 2 Prices** for every Item that existed that day.

So, if I was looking at the last day (2023-04-13) I would get something like this:

```py
[
{'id': '1i', 'latest_prices': [{'price__id': '8p', 'price__per_item': 12.0}, {'price__id': '4p', 'price__per_item': 11.0}]
{'id': '2i', 'latest_prices': [{'price__id': '9p', 'price__per_item': 3.5}, {'price__id': '6p', 'price__per_item': 2.0}]
{'id': '3i', 'latest_prices': [{'price__id': '10p', 'price__per_item': 15.0}, {'price__id': '7p', 'price__per_item': 14.5}]
]
```

I have ~25k items every day, so I'd like not to:

- Have to go to the database for every `Price` to retrieve its `per_item` field
- Have to loop through every `Item` of every day, to retrieve its last 2 `Price`s

#### What I have tried

1. I have tried using `annotate` and `Subquery`, but I was getting `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`
2. Then I found that on postgres I could use an [`ArraySubquery`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/postgres/expressions/#arraysubquery-expressions) but I could only return multiple `price__id`, not multiple fields
3. Then I looked closer at the example in the `ArraySubquery` link and I noticed the `JSONObject` - however I'm probably holding it the wrong way and I always get a single item in the `latest_prices` annotation.

I *suspect* that the solution is in the `JSONObject` approach, but somehow it's just out of reach for my mind at the moment, so any steer in the right direction is really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so the answer is indeed a combination of `ArraySubquery` and `JSONObject` and it looks like this:

```py
subquery = (
    Price.objects.filter(item__id=OuterRef("id"))
        .filter(timestamp__lt=end_of_today)
        .order_by("-retrieval__timestamp")
        .values(json=JSONObject(price_id="id", per_item="per_item"))[:2]
    )

items_with_prices = (
    Item.objects.filter(id__in=item_ids)
        .annotate(latest_prices=ArraySubquery(subquery))
        .values("id", "latest_prices")
)
```

The reason it was not working for me is because I had forgotten a debugging statement that restricted how many days back I could look ‍♂️